# Pick a record based on the value of one column being the greatest in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rank

Let's say I have a table structured like this

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | 40 |
| Mike | 79 |
| Mike | 49 |

And I wanted to return just the row that says Mike with the score of 79 and nothing else.

The code I have been playing around with looks like this:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name), greatest(Score) FROM
table GROUP BY Name, Score
```

I tried a few different variations like using Rank and the greatest function, but haven't had too much luck. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Assuming you have other names in your table, then I would recommend changing your sample data and also clarify the problem and output. As you currently have it, it looks like your table has just one name in it, so the solution is obvious. But I suspect that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why other answers are complicating things, you just want to be using the [max](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min.html#min-max) function, like so:

```
WITH data(name, score) as (
    select * from values
    ('Mike', 40),
    ('Mike', 79),
    ('Mike', 79)
)

select name, max(score) as score
from data 
where name ='Mike' group by name;
```

With your query:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*), max(Score) FROM
table GROUP BY Name
```

`greatest` is "similar" to max from a functionality perspective but as you mentioned it did not work, that's because of it's signature - it's not meant to receive a single expr as input. I recommend you read about the [differences between max and greatest](https://database.guide/max-vs-greatest-in-mysql-whats-the-difference/) to make sure you understand them fully.

Comment: I like the approach of using MAX with group by clause. applying qualify logic is costlier usually.

Answer (score 1):

Using QUALIFY and RANK/ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Score DESC) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The long form explanation:

If you add a [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html), and a [RANK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rank.html) to the altered data:

```
WITH data(name, score, extra) as (
    select * from values
    ('Mike', 40, 'a'),
    ('Mike', 79, 'b'),
    ('Mike', 79, 'c')
)
select *
    ,row_number() over (partition by name order by score desc) as rn
    ,rank() over (partition by name order by score desc) as rank
from data;
```

| NAME | SCORE | EXTRA | RN | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 79 | b | 1 | 1 |
| Mike | 79 | c | 2 | 1 |
| Mike | 40 | a | 3 | 3 |

You can see that ROW_NUMBER will only assign the value 1 to one value, where RANK will give you as many values that hold that spot, and in the case of sparse RANK there will be gaps, as `Mike,40` is the third value. So the choice between RANK/ROW_NUMBER depends how you want to handle the results and if you are joining to this data etc.

Then you can do a filter in the classic ANSI form:

```
WITH data(name, score, extra) as (
    select * from values
    ('Mike', 40, 'a'),
    ('Mike', 79, 'b'),
    ('Mike', 79, 'c')
)
select name, score, extra
from (
    select *
        ,row_number() over (partition by name order by score desc) as rn
    from data
)
where rn = 1;
```

Note this is an unstable sort, as Mike,79,b OR Mike,79,c can be returned by the database, but with ROW_NUMBER you will only get one.

Snowflake has the [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) command which allows dropping the sub-select, and having another filter run after grouping is complete.

So you can write:

```
select *
    ,row_number() over (partition by name order by score desc) as rn
from data
QUALIFY rn = 1;
```

| NAME | SCORE | EXTRA | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 79 | b | 1 |

but if you do not want to see the ROW_NUMBER value, it can be moved to the QUALIFY and the scope time is the exact same as the query, but it makes things tidier:

```
WITH data(name, score, extra) as (
    select * from values
    ('Mike', 40, 'a'),
    ('Mike', 79, 'b'),
    ('Mike', 79, 'c')
)
select *
from data
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by name order by score desc) = 1;
```

| NAME | SCORE | EXTRA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 79 | b |

Answer (score 0):

MAX_BY is probably what you need https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/max_by

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Maybe you can [edit] your answer and write code that demonstrates how the OP would use MAX_BY in order to obtain his desired [query] result?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35765721)